# R - spliting matrix to run multiple statistical tests

Tags: r, matrix, split

I am trying to analyze survey data. The survey has 60 items, each of which are scored on a 1-5 likert scale. The survey was given to participants before and after an intervention. I want to see if their responses changed from pre to post.

I have my data ordered so that row 1 is question 1 pretest, row 2 is question 1 posttest, etc. These are counts (e.g., question 1 pretest 8 people answered with a 5 on the likert scale). Like so:

```
    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
1   0   1   2   1   8
2   0   0   1   2   10
3   0   0   4   5   4
4   0   0   2   5   6
```

I therefore have 160 lines of data (2 for each of the 60 questions). In order to run stats on each question (like a fisher's test) I need each question to be it's own matrix. So, I need to split the data into something like this:

```
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  0  1  2  1  8
[2,]  0  0  1  2 10
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  0  0  4  5  4
[2,]  0  0  2  5  6
```

I got this to work using the isplitRows command, but that command doesn't seem to save the matrices. Does anyone know how to save these? Or to run a test on the small matrices resulting from the isplitRows command? Here is the code I currently have. It nicely displays what I want, but I can't figure out how to use it.

```
   #tools needed
library(iterators)
library(itertools)
#read data
primatedata<- read.delim("~/Desktop/primate attitudes/pairedforr.txt", header=T)
#take out the first two columns which are not numerical
data=primatedata[,-c(1,2)]
#convert to matrix
dm<-as.matrix(data)
#split into matrices by question (to compare time 1 and 2)
it <- ihasNext(isplitRows(dm, chunkSize=2))
while (hasNext(it)) {
 print(nextElem(it))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do, but I think you are looking for a simple split:

```
split(mat,rep(seq(1,nrow(mat)/2),each=2))

$`1`
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  1  2  1  8
2  0  0  1  2 10

$`2`
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
3  0  0  4  5  4
4  0  0  2  5  6
```

Where `mat` is :

```
mat <- read.table(text='    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
1   0   1   2   1   8
2   0   0   1   2   10
3   0   0   4   5   4
4   0   0   2   5   6')
```

Comment: On a side note, if the input `mat` is a matrix, the code produces a different result, it seems. If it is a data.frame, it is as described.

Comment: @beginneR good point.(+1). You can still use something like :  `lapply(split(as.matrix(mat),rep(seq(1,nrow(mat)/2),each=2)),matrix,nrow=2)`

Comment: agstudy, thanks for adding that `matrix` approach (which indeed produces the result). I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: @beginneR you are welcom. Though. I am not sure that it is the best method.

Comment: Thanks all, this was very helpful. I did want them in a matrix, so agstudy's code worked best for me.